# How can I add signatures to Preview.app in Lion without using the web cam?

Tags: macos, preview, signature

Is it possible to add a signature e.g. from PDF files or from JPEG images instead of using a web cam? The problem is that I don't have a web cam and I would like to use this feature in spite of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that at present, that isn't an option. When I created a signature file using the FaceTime camera, I see that first of all, there is no unencrypted graphic file created by Preview. Preview did a new key in Keychain titled "Preview signature privacy", suggesting that the signature files go directly from Preview's camera interface to an encrypted file. There isn't a supported way to add a graphic as a signature, and the encryption makes it difficult to bypass the approved new signature process.

Comment: That keychain entry is only a password to decrypt a file, it isn't the image file itself. So there's a file...some place on disk there's a file for the image.

Comment: Good call! Where ever it's hidden, I haven't been able to find it yet, but I'll keep looking

Comment: I also don't have a webcam so I am unable to test it, but perhaps [FSEventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) would be of some use in locating that file?